# How to redirect to a page with an object in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a couple of vue pages, one page is a list of users, the second is a list of permissions and the third is a vue component
that displays the list of users and another vue component that shows the details of a user.

What I'm trying to do is, if I'm on the permissions page and I would like to go to a specific user's details I would like to redirect
with that panel open.

I am able to redirect the the users page by doing `window.location.href = '/admin/users';` but I'm not sure how I'm going to get
the user panel open.

I thought that if I could do `$emit` then that could pass the user object over to the users main page, but that won't work if I do
a `window.location.href = '/admin/users';`

Here is my code. This has 2 components displays a list of users and their details

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <users :emit="emit" :users="users"></users>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <detail v-if="userDetails" :emit="emit" :user="manageUser"></detail>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['emit', 'users'],
        data() {
            return {
                userDetails: false,
                manageUser: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.emit.$on('user', payload => {
                this.manageUser = payload.user;
                this.userDetails = true;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my users lists

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title text-success" style="cursor: pointer;" @click="createUser"> New User</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th style="width:120px;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="user in users">
                      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                      <td style="text-align: right;">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" @click="detail(user)">Details</button>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['emit', 'users'],
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            detail(user) {
                this.emit.$emit('user', { user: user });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is my permissions pages

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{permission.name}}</strong></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body p-0">
            <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User Name</th>
                        <th style="width:120px;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="user in users">
                        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" @click="detail(user)">Details</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['emit'],
        data() {
            return {
              users: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.allUsers();
        },
        methods: {

            allUsers() {
                this.loading = true;
                axios.get('/users').then(response => {
                    this.users = response.data.users;
                });
            },
            detail(user) {
                window.location.href = '/admin/users';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you use a client router (e.g. [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/))?

Comment: @ShayaUlman - sorry my reply is late, but yes I do. I use vue router